# Plot graph from different rows of data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and vector (of times for time series) and want to apply a plot function to each row of the matrix to create a time series graph.

I've made this function

```
plotting=function(x,y,xlab="",ylab="",main="",colour){
    plot.window(xaxs="i",yaxs="i",xlim=range(x),ylim=range(y))
    plot(x,row,type="l",xlab="xaxis",ylab="yaxis",main="Pop")
    polygon(c(min(x), x, max(x)), c(-1, y, -1), colour)
}
```

And given the time and data frame

```
x=1950:1960
popdata=
 female pop 1 3 4 5 6 7 4 3 3 2
 male pop   3 4 5 2 2 2 4 5 6 8
```

I want to plot both data rows on the same graph with a different colour band under each observation.
Please note that I'm trying to make this code generalised so it should work for more than two groups.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does it have to be base R? Ggplot2 might be your friend here, your function makes a new plot each time...

Comment: @Heroka I'm wanting to access the different rows of the matrix and apply the plot function, while changing the colour each time. If I had par(new=TRUE) would this solve the new plot problem?

Comment: Can you show exactly what your data looks like, and how you've been attempting to plot (even just one row?)

Comment: @Heroka I tried to use for `(i in 1:now(y))` but I keep getting `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Comment: Also I transposed x so that it would have the same number of columns as the popdata

Comment: I think I'm repeating myself here, but please help us to help you. When I have to start to make guesses about what your data looks like (is it a matrix with 10 rows and 3 columns in this example? Or another format?) and what it is you're trying to achieve, (should time be on the x-axis with a line for men and a line for women? Something else?) it's not easy to help out.

Comment: @Heroka sorry I must've misinterpreted your comment. So in the real R code I have x=1926:2014 and then a vector of values for both female and males from the population. I then, create a data frame from these two vectors `popudata=data.frame(femalepop,male pop)`,
`popdata=as.data.frame(t(popudata))` which I then get the cumulative sum so that it will be easier to plot in the series `popdata[]= lapply((popdata), cumsum)`

Comment: And what is your desired output? A line/polygon per group?

Comment: @Heroka I'm trying to create a time series of a population broken down into factors (gender in this example). So the x axis would be for both female and men. And the colour would be the filler between these lines. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Heroka yes thats it. I thought that using cumsum would make it easier because the first would be the whole population (e.g. female + male) and then filling this to the x axis. And then the population lines would continually get smaller ((female+male)-male) so that the polygons could overlap and still be alright

Comment: But how do you extend this to multiple groups? Why not just have line/polygon per group?

Comment: @Heroka Because the data is added together to make the whole population. I'm not sure if my approach is the best now, thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first part to play with. Generally when you're plotting and you're doing the same thing with each row/column, it's easiest to turn your data to a format where each line is one observation, and as such includes data on x, y and grouping.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
###generate some data
popdata <- data.frame(x=1950:1960,fempop=sample(2:7,11,T),malepop=sample(2:7,11,T))

#turn to long format for plotting
m_df <- melt(popdata,id.var="x")

p1 <- ggplot(m_df, aes(x=factor(x),y=value,group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("malepop"="blue","fempop"="red"))
p1
```

[image]

Or, polygons over time:

```
#first, calculate totals per group
m_df <- m_df %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(group_total=cumsum(value))


p2 <- ggplot(m_df, aes(x=x,y=group_total,group=variable, colour=variable,fill=variable)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=0.3, aes(ymin=0,ymax=group_total)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("malepop"="blue","fempop"="red"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("malepop"="blue","fempop"="red"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1950,1960,by=5))
```

[image]